# BASH Script to run command based in variable

Tags: bash

Basically i have a script which i'm planning on running which will view the current status of an OpenVPN connection and re-connect if the status is not "VPN 'ibVPN is running" however it seems regardless of if the connection is running or not, it still tries to re-connect as part of this script.

I have manually run the command vpncon=("/etc/init.d/openvpn status") and then checked the results of this in terminal, which after running come out as " * VPN 'ibVPN' is running" so it looks to be passing the information over. I fear i'm not quite grasping how i then need to enter my if state text to match this.

Basically i want if $vpncon =  * VPN 'ibVPN' is running then don't run the script/
If $vpncon is not  * VPN 'ibVPN' is running, run the script.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash +x
while [ "true" ]
do
        vpncon=("/etc/init.d/openvpn status")
        if [[ $vpncon != *"VPN 'ibVPN' is running"* ]]; then
                echo "Disconnected, trying to reconnect..."
                (sleep 1s && sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn start ibVPN)
        else
                echo "Already connected !"
        fi
        sleep 30
done
```

Comment: `vpncon=("/etc/init.d/openvpn status")` does not run the command `/etc/init.d/openvpn`; it only make `vpncon` an array that contains _the string_ `/etc/init.d/openvpn status` as its first field.

Answer (score 1):

In your case vnpncon is the value `"/etc/init.d/openvpn status"` and not the result of that command. You should use `$("command")` instead. Also in your condition `[[ $vpncon != *"VPN 'ibVPN' is running"* ]];` you should use double quotes for `$vpncon`.

This should work

```
#!/bin/bash +x
while true
do
        vpncon="$(/etc/init.d/openvpn status)"
        if [[ "$vpncon" != *"VPN 'ibVPN' is running"* ]]; then
                echo "Disconnected, trying to reconnect..."
                (sleep 1s && sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn start ibVPN)
        else
                echo "Already connected !"
        fi
        sleep 30
done
```

Comment: Great, these work a treat and it's now up and running. Can someone confirm if this is a safe script to rely on if i run it from crontab @reboot? Any chance it will terminate and not relaunch or is it best to call the script from cron every hour or so?

Comment: When you start by cron, you must delete the `while true` or make something that check for this script running already.

Comment: I think it is more reliable to rely on CRON and remove the while loop completely